# How to get all the records which have EventDate greater than today from a Calendar list using angualrjs $http

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

PFB my code:

```
var myApp4=angular.module("upcomingEvents",[]);
    myApp4.controller("upcomingEventsController",function($scope,$http)
    {
    $scope.today=new Date();
    $scope.today=$scope.today.toISOString();
    $http({ 
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('Calendar')/items?$filter=EventDate ge datetime'"+$scope.today+"'", 
    method: "GET", 
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" } 
    }).then(function success(data)
    {
    $scope.events=data.data.d.results;



    },
function error(data)
    {

    });
});
```

But am getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Dheeraj, Please go through this link http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/12/rest-filter-datetime/
This might be help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the ISOString.
The query fails since it contains the `:`:

```
"/_api/lists/getbytitle('Calendar')/items?$filter=EventDate ge datetime'2018-01-01T00:00:00'"
```

Encoding it you get:

```
"/_api/lists/getbytitle('Calendar')/items?$filter=EventDate ge datetime'2014-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%0A'"
```

Comment: I tred to encode it using EncodeURIComponent but still no use

Comment: Do you still get BadRequest?